# VS2008 View designer / View code shortcut

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any VS2008 shortcut for switching between View designer / View code? I am working on c# projects and I switch these two views a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS addin: View markup. Does exists something like that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554667/vs-addin-view-markup-does-exists-something-like-that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

- <kbd>F7</kbd> - Form to code
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> - Code to Form

For more shortcuts you can refer to 
http://www.dofactory.com/ShortCutKeys/ShortCutKeys.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This one is for vs2008 asp.net web site development:

- <kbd>F7</kbd> - from from to code (aspx to aspx.cs)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> - from code to form  (aspx.cs to aspx)

Visual C# 2008 Keybinding Reference Poster:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e5f902a8-5bb5-4cc6-907e-472809749973&displaylang=en