# How to make a round trip - start from markup - in Visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, editor

In a aspx page, source/markup mode, I can

**Right-Click > View Code**  <kbd>F7</kbd>

This bring me to cs file, good. when I want to go back,

**Right-Click > View Designer** <kbd>Shift+ F7</kbd>

This bring me to aspx design mode which is very slow. I need source/markup mode.

My question is
how to use **KeyBoard** to make a real round trip?

---

**Update:** Thanks Ben. I followed your link, it works for me! I use VS 2012.

[VS addin: View markup. Does exist something like that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554667/vs-addin-view-markup-does-exist-something-like-that)

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS addin: View markup. Does exist something like that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554667/vs-addin-view-markup-does-exist-something-like-that)

Answer (score 2):

Your version of Visual Studio is not included, but for VS2012 and VS2010 (at least), you can switch between `Design` and `Source` views with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>.

So to go from .CS to .ASPX, simply press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> twice.

The roundtrip will look like :

`.aspx` => <kbd>F7</kbd> => `.cs` => <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> => `.aspx`

The `Design` view will still try to load some stuff on the first visit even if you switch very fast, so there's still a slight delay when accessing `Source` view.

Comment: The question points out that it's too slow to switch to designer mode.

Comment: @brz The switch occurs before it's completely loaded, and there's no loading times on the following attempts.